# Plane curves admitting several ways to seal it up by the disc

Tags: reference-request, plane-curves, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $\gamma:S^1\to\mathbb R^2$ be an immersed closed curve with only isolated transversal self-intersections. Say that $\gamma$ is *sealed by the disc* if there is an immersion $f:D^2\to\mathbb R^2$ such that $f|_{\partial D^2}=\gamma$.

It is easy to see that if $\gamma$ admits sealing by the disc then the rotation number of $\gamma$ is $\pm1$. But how can I understand whether or not a given curve admits sealing by the disc?

More surprisingly, there exists curves admitting several inequivalent ways to seal it up by the disc. For example, this one:

[image]

Here is the first way:

[image]

And here is the second way:

[image]

In fact, this curve may be drawn on a higher genus surface instead the plane. Does any theory tell us when we can seal it up by the disc (or, maybe, by the surface of largest genus) and how many ways we can do it? I would like any references about this problem.

Comment: The answer is a bit complicated; see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100224/which-immersed-plane-curves-bound-an-immersed-disc). Of course, if the curve has no self-intersections, it's trivial.

Comment: Is there an obvious rotation number 1 example without such an immersed disk?

Comment: I made some edits in order to try and improve readability a bit. Please revert them if they messed up your question in some way.

Comment: @PVAL, no, it's correct, thank you. [anomaly](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/156999/anomaly)'s link to [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100224/which-immersed-plane-curves-bound-an-immersed-disc) in the first comment is, in fact, an answer